# Deriving a relation from system of two ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find the geodesics of a certain surface, but I still haven't taken a differential equations course (such is the curriculum), so I'm having trouble with the resulting system of differential equations.

The system is $$u''-\frac{u}{3}(v')^2=0,\\
v''+\frac{2}{u}u'v'=0.$$

I need to prove $$v=\pm \int \frac{C\sqrt{3}}{u\sqrt{u^2-C^2}}du,$$ where $C$ is a constant.

The only thing I know how to do is separate variables in the second equations, obtaining $\frac{v''}{v'}=-2\frac{u'}{u}$, and from there $$v'=\frac{1}{Cu^2}.$$ However, when I plug this into the first equation, I get $u''-\frac{1}{3C^2u^3}=0,$ which I have no idea how to approach.

Is there a better general approach to this problem?

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that the curve is unit-speed parametrized, so there's an extra condition $3(u')^2+u^2(v')^2=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out the solution:

By multiplying the second equation with $u^2$ , I get $u^2v''+2uu'v'=0$, which is equivalent to $(u^2v')'=0,$ so $u^2v'=C,$ and $v'=\frac{C}{u^2}$.

Now, I omitted (not on purpose) an important detail in my question, which is that my curve was unit-speed parametrized, meaning in my case $3(u')^2 + u^2(v')^2=1$ (the coefficients of the first fundamental form were $3$, $0$ and $u^2$), so I've added that to the question's description for clarity's sake. From there, I easily obtained $u'=\pm\sqrt{\frac{u^2-C^2}{3u^2}}$, $\frac{dv}{du}=\pm\frac{C\sqrt{3}}{u\sqrt{u^2-C^2}}$, and from there the necessary expression.